# Facebook login button disappeared, when set scope

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I almost copy the code from [FB tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web) (replace the appId).

It was worked by FB's default code. (Everything include login and authorize has worked)

After the basic process is ok, I want to try the special permission from user (FB have authorizeed the permission for APP), so I need to set scope on fb:login-button.

But when I try to set ***scope="name,user_posts"*** on fb:login-button label like the above.

```
<fb:login-button scope="name,user_posts" onlogin="checkLoginState();"></fb:login-button>
```

And then the login button disappeared.... Why?
(I use another user to test)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must be some very old tutorial, this is what the login button generator presents:

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="medium" data-button-type="continue_with" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="false" data-scope="user_posts"></div>
```

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/login-button

Btw, there is no permission called "name", afaik that one never even existed. You get the name of the user without extra permissions.

Comment: You saved my problem!! because the permission "name" is not exist~ thx!!!